# How to autofocus a headlessUi (tailwind) select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

When I open one page I need to have the select already open. I use [this tailwindcss select](https://headlessui.dev/react/listbox)

I tried this

```
<Listbox value={selectedPerson} onChange={setSelectedPerson}>
  //Listbox.Button has a prop called autoFocus
  <Listbox.Button autoFocus={true}>{selectedPerson.name}</Listbox.Button>
  <Listbox.Options>
    {people.map((person) => (
      <Listbox.Option
        key={person.id}
        value={person}
        disabled={person.unavailable}
      >
        {person.name}
      </Listbox.Option>
    ))}
  </Listbox.Options>
</Listbox>
```

The prop "autofocus" exists but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The `autoFocus` prop only focuses the Listbox component so only then you can hit `enter` or `space` to open the options menu, but if you want to open the options menu when the component mounts you can simulate a click on the ListBox.Button component and that would open your options menu.

```
const buttonRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  if (buttonRef.current) {
    buttonRef.current.click();
  }
}, [])
```

```
<Listbox value={selectedPerson} onChange={setSelectedPerson}>
  <Listbox.Button ref={buttonRef} autoFocus={true}>{selectedPerson.name}</Listbox.Button>
  <Listbox.Options>
    {people.map((person) => (
      <Listbox.Option
        key={person.id}
        value={person}
        disabled={person.unavailable}
      >
        {person.name}
      </Listbox.Option>
    ))}
  </Listbox.Options>
</Listbox>
```